# Error in my python script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a new question.
Here my script.
I try to compute a pay with an extra for overtime.
I can't understand the problem here:

```
def computePay(Hours,Rate):
 print 'Enter Hours:\t'
 Hours = float (raw_input())
 print 'Enter Rate:\t'
 Rate = float (raw_input())
 try:
  if Hours > 40:
   R1 = print 'Pay:', (Hours-40)*Rate*1.5 + (40*Rate)
   return R1
  else:
   R2 = print 'Pay:', (Hours*Rate)
   return R2
 except:
  print 'Error, please enter numeric input!'
```

Some help please.
I'm new to programming

Comment: What is your problem? Would you describe it a little more precisely?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do when you say `R1 = print 'Pay:', (Hours-40)*Rate*1.5 + (40*Rate)`

Comment: I have an invalid synthax

Comment: I want to compute the pay

Comment: Never use a bare "except" handler. It hides the true nature of your problem.

Comment: I think he wants to calculate 150% of the hourly rate for each hour which is more than 40.

Comment: In python indentation is crucial. Please format your code. As it stands here it is not valid python code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issues are in this lines:

```
R1 = print 'Pay:', (Hours-40)*Rate*1.5 + (40*Rate)
R2 = print 'Pay:', (Hours*Rate)
```

- **You cannot use `print` when assigning a string to a variable**

If you want to asign a string to R1 and R2 you should do:

```
R1 = 'Pay: ' + str((Hours-40)*Rate*1.5) + str((40*Rate))
R2 = 'Pay:' + str((Hours*Rate))
```

or you can also do:

```
R1 = 'Pay: %.2f  %.2f' % ( ((Hours-40)*Rate*1.5),  (40*Rate) )
R2 = 'Pay: %.2f' % ( Hours*Rate )
```

- Change `%.2f` for `%.Nf` being `N` number of decimals

Your function should be:

```
def computePay():
    print 'Enter Hours:\t'
    Hours = float (raw_input())
    print 'Enter Rate:\t'
    Rate = float (raw_input())
    try:
        if Hours > 40:
            R1 = 'Pay: %.2f  %.2f' % ( ((Hours-40)*Rate*1.5),  (40*Rate) )
            return R1
        else:
            R2 = 'Pay: %.2f' % ( Hours*Rate )
            return R2
    except:
        print 'Error, please enter numeric input!'
```

If you execute the code you'll get:

```
Enter Hours:    
20
Enter Rate: 
8
Pay: 160.00
```

## Tips

- **Indentation is very important in Python ! You should check** [Pep8 Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)
- Your function name was `def computePay(Hours,Rate):` but you're not sending **Hours** or **Rate**. You're asking for them in the function, so the name should be `def computePay():`
- There is several ways to `manage/concatenate` strings in **Python**, and is very useful to have little knowledge on this, to choose the best solution for each situation. there is a useful and sample tutorial for this: [String concatenation and formatting in Python](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python)

Comment: let me check. I want the user to put theirs Hours and rate so that He can have his Pay.    Enter Hours: 45
    Enter Rate: 10
    Pay: 475.0

Comment: @user3438349 check the answer now, at the end is your function without errors